# Exchange 2003 to send NDR to the intended recipient

Tags: exchange-2003

Is it possible to configure Exchange 2003 to send an NDR to the intended recipient when a message doesn't reach them?

For example, if an external sender attempts to send a message which is over our size limit, then they will receive an NDR, and I (as the System Administrator) also get notified. The intended recipient is oblivious though.